# How to scrape multiple links stored in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape multiple pages of an url by applying each pagenumber to the url and then storing the urls in a list.
When executing the iteration only the content from the first page is scraped and not the rest. Where is the fault?

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
list_of_links = []
url = 'https://marknadssok.fi.se/publiceringsklient?Page='
    for link in range(1,10):
        urls = url + str(link)
        list_of_links.append(urls)

 #Establish connection

    for i in list_of_links:
        r = requests.get(i)
        html = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

#Append each column to it's attribute

        table_body=html.find('tbody')
        rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
        data = []
        for row in rows:
            cols=row.find_all('td')
            cols=[x.text.strip() for x in cols]
            data.append(cols)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Publiceringsdatum', 'utgivare', 'person', 'befattning',
                             'Närstående', 'karaktär', 'Instrumentnamn', 'ISIN', 'transaktionsdatum',
                             'volym', 'volymsenhet', 'pris', 'valuta', 'handelsplats', 
                             'status', 'detaljer' ])
```

Comment: There are some mistake in you posted code. Revise indent line 5.  Line 6 variable page should be link???

Comment: @wonka My misstake, excuse me! Fixed it

Comment: It can be because of cookies required. Try print the link before you append it and manually dumping the html in a `python` or `ipython` prompt.

Comment: @PMHui the links seems to work in the prompt, did a requests.get and it didn't produce any error/failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the data variable which stored the content from the url was in the for-loop meaning. Solved it by taking it out of the for-loop